# ES6 +new Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am seeing this ES6 syntax around the web recently:

```
let queriedAt = +new Date();
```

What does the `+new` do?

Comment: `+` is just the unary plus operator. It serves the purpose of converting the Date object into a number (a timestamp). Try it on the console, with and without the plus.

Comment: To clarify, the plus is executed against `new Date()` variable, not the `new` keyword. The duplicate answer should explain the rest